# Equation with error Misplaced alignment tab character &. and hbox overfull

Tags: align

```
\begin{equation} \label{Vivi2}
     \dot{r}_{i}^{\text{in}} + \sum_{\omega}^{\Omega}(f^\omega\dot{r}_i^{\omega, \text{in}} -f^\omega\dot{r}_i^{\omega, \text{out}}) = \dot{r}_{i}^{\text{out}} \quad\forall i 
\end{equation}
   
\begin{equation}\label{Vivi3}
   R_{k-1} + \sum_{\omega}^{\Omega} f^\omega\sum_{n}^{N} \dot{Q}_k^\omega = R_{k} \quad\forall k  
\end{equation}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If I insert your code fragment into small working document, it works fine: no errors, no warning, no bad boxes. However, why you use `align`? In your case it will be better to use `equation` instead it. For further help please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which we can compile as it is and which reproduce your problem.

Comment: Unrelated note that `\text` does not do that you think it does, you might want to use `\mathrm` or `\textrm` instead.

Comment: please show a full example, but why do you have align with just an aligned, so it is a 1-row-1-column alignment??

Comment: @Samantha Please edit your question to include a short test document which allows us to reproduce your error. It should start with a class and include all necessary packages.